# Hybrid of mergeMap and concatMap in rxjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I'm working one a back-end app and I have a situation where I'm getting events from users. For each event I'm going to do a call to some endpoint `foo`. If I have several events from the same user, I want to do the next `foo` call after previous call to `foo` is finished (concatMap behaviour). At the same time, for different users calls have to be done in parallel (mergeMap behaviour).

In the code it looks something like this:

```
const userEvent$: Observable<{userId: string}> = ...
const foo: (userId: string) => Observable<Response> = ...

let result$: Observable<Response> = ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider utilizing the [GroupBy](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/groupBy) operator, to group events by `userId`, next apply `concatMap` to the group, so that events within the same group are executed sequentially,  as demonstrated in the example below:

```
 userEvent$.pipe(
           groupBy(item => item.userId),
           mergeMap(group => group.pipe(concatMap(x => foo(x.userId))))
  );
```

**Demo:**

```js
const { of, from } = rxjs;
const { delay, tap, concatMap, mergeMap, groupBy } = rxjs.operators;

function foo(userId, index) {
  return of(userId).pipe(
    delay(2000),
    tap(() => console.log("UserId: ", userId, ", Occurrences: ", index + 1))
  )
}


const userEvent$ = from([
  { userId: 1 }, // <- first 
  { userId: 2 }, // <- first 
  { userId: 2 }, // <- second 
  { userId: 3 },// <- first  
  { userId: 1 }, // <- second 
  { userId: 1 }, // <- third 
  { userId: 2 }, // <- third 
  { userId: 3 }, // <- second            
]);

userEvent$
  .pipe(
    groupBy(x => x.userId),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(concatMap((x,i) => foo(x.userId,i)))),
  )
  .subscribe()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As far as I know, `groupBy` operator expects `userEvent$` observable to complete before it starts emiting any items. So this solution will not work in real time (when `userEvent$` does not complete).

Comment: what makes you think so? try  `userEvent$ = timer(0,1000).pipe(map(x => ({userId:x})))`